# use rjs for reading values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjs

I want to use the value of an input tag in rjs

to do:

```
<%= button_to_function "add tag" do |page|
page.insert_html :bottom, :selected_tags, :partial => 'tag', :object => Tag.new(:name => "#{page[:tag_name].value}" )
 end %>
```

But it throws an alert:

```
RJS error:

TypeError: $("tag_name").value is not a function
```

Is there a way to use rjs syntax to read values of tag elements ?

Comment: I tried page << "function getTagNameVal(id){return $(id).value} " and then call it with page.call 'getTagNameVal', :tag_name but this also doesn't returns a value, but returns the true value in a alert box, if I use page << "alert(getTagNameVal('tag_name')" after.

Comment: hmm page.call 'getTagNameVal', :tag_name does not call a method. It just generates the string getTagNameVal("tag_name");"

Answer (score 2):

Wait a second:

```
<%= button_to_function "add tag" do |page|
page.insert_html :bottom, :selected_tags, :partial => 'tag', :object => Tag.new(:name => "#{page[:tag_name].value}" )
 end %>
```

button_to_function and the page.insert_html happen when the pages gets rendered (object creation, rendering, etc). Only the actual INSERT happens when the user clicks the button.

I'd suggest that you:

1. use a link_to_remote or a form_to_remoe (t
2. create the Tag object then in a action on the server side, and render the partial
3. send it back to the client and add it to the selected_tags list by rjs (render update do page)

Cheers
Reto

Comment: Thaks, link_to_remote and sending the tag value  would do it. But I was thinking if there is a way to do more sophisticated preparations, using the clean rjs syntax, before or even with out sending a server request.

Answer (score 1):

@reto is right, you have to distinguish client and server-side. The JS generated in the `link_to_button` block will be executed at the client, but **the partial is rendered at the server**, so there is no way your code can work.

The `link_to_remove` option proposed is easy to implement, but it could be improved, as you would be connecting the server for something you already know when the view is rendered. Don't fear JavaScript and:

- server: send a HTML template
- client: substitute the values when the button is pressed
- client: insert the new HTML block in the container.

There are many ways of accomplishing that, play a little bit with it to figure it out.

Comment: I was looking for a solution, which would be solved on the client side. But this was not a good example because I used a partial which requires a server request anyway :)

Comment: I just check the generated source code. And I saw that the partial is not requested at server side, as I thought , but is inserted directly inline between the local generated javascript so this could be still be a good example for solving everything on the client side :)

Comment: @vurte, there are two cases: one in which every "new" action creates a tag on the server (you would use link_to_remote + RJS), and other (more form-like) where objects are only saved on post (then you would use something like I've explained, purely client-side). Do you want to see an example of the latter?

Comment: thanks @tokland, I took your advice and just returned to plain js.

Comment: I forgot to mention: the upward trend is towards unobtrusive Javascript, and some libraries have emerged these last years (apply_behaviour, lowpro, etc).